# T4 generation in Pre-Build event

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4

I have a project which includes a tt file and for the operation it performs I need to use some third party libraries. All these dlls are added as a reference to the project which contains the tt file.

In tt class I have the external dlls referenced as here:

```
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq" #>
```

I have tried with full path, targetDir, sourceDir, using T4ParameterValues in csproj, but each time I use "Run Custom Tool" on tt file I receive this error: (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE  to my path, no matter what I use).

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE**Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq.dll'.
File name: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq.dll'

The thing is that it works when I run it from command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\14.0\TextTransform.exe" ComponentsGuids.tt -out ComponentsGuids.cs
```

I am just curious why it does not work from VS (I am using VS2015)?

An another problem that I have is that it does not work as a Pre-Build event, that I want to be triggered when the project is build on release mode

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release texttransform $(ProjectDir)ComponentsGuids.tt
```